# AWS elastic beanstalk UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Cannot find ffprobe

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ffprobe

Using elasticbeanstalk with Node.js 10 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.2.3. I have a *packages.config* file under *.ebextensions* folder.

```
   packages:
  yum:
    ImageMagick: []
    ImageMagick-devel: []
commands:
  01-wget:
    command: "wget -O /tmp/ffmpeg.tar.xz http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-4.1.tar.gz"
  02-mkdir:
    command: "if [ ! -d /opt/ffmpeg ] ; then mkdir -p /opt/ffmpeg; fi"
  03-tar:
    command: "tar xvf /tmp/ffmpeg.tar.xz -C /opt/ffmpeg"
  04-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffmpeg ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.1/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg; fi"
  05-ln:
    command: "if [[ ! -f /usr/bin/ffprobe ]] ; then ln -sf /opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.1/ffprobe /usr/bin/ffprobe; fi"
  06-pecl:
    command: "if [ `pecl list | grep imagick` ] ; then pecl install -f imagick; fi"
```

I am using **fluent-ffmpeg**@2.1.2 module for saving screenshot.

Comment: Did you inspect EB log files for more detailed error messages?

Comment: yes @Marcin
`Dec 31 11:41:54 ip-172-31-46-171 web: Cannot process video: Error: Cannot find ffprobe
Dec 31 11:41:54 ip-172-31-46-171 web: (node:10094) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Cannot find ffprobe
Dec 31 11:41:54 ip-172-31-46-171 web: (node:10094) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are just downloading and unpacking the source code of `ffmpeg`. Before you can use `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` you have to **compile** the code. Without this, your scripts will not work.

To compile, you can try run the following commands in `/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.1` folder:

```
./configure  --disable-x86asm
make
```

However, compilation will be **time consuming**. This it would be better probably to compile everything, store the binaries in S3 for example, or bundle with your application zip, to save a lot of time.